# Getting ENOENT error in git path when running npm test

Tags: node.js, git, npm, nvm, enoent

Firstly i want to apologize in advance for the poor english.

I'm following the path made by The Odin Project to learn web development, so im fairly new into coding and the use of linux/ubuntu, just started to use node.js, there are some exercises where i meed to use **npm test** and i'm running in the following error:

> ```
> Exception has occurred: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/josevia/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/git'
>   at Object.statSync (node:fs:1536:3)
>     at Object.statSync (/home/josevia/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:312:16)
>     at Function.sync (/home/josevia/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:13:23)
>     at Function.sync (/home/josevia/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:49:17)
>     at Function.whichSync [as sync] (/home/josevia/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:104:26)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/josevia/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/git/lib/which.js:5:19)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> ```

I looked for some solutions but none of them did solve my problem, even reinstalled node and nvm. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The only thing this has to do with Git is that there is no file named `bin/git` installed at the location where the node.js code is looking for it.  Whether there *should* be, and if not, what the node.js code should be doing instead, is another question entirely.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?